# What is the reason for java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes

Tags: java, pdf, file-io, base64, ioexception

Here is my code, `imageFile` is a `pdf` file, intent is to get `Base64` encoded file for image file. I am using `Java6` and no possibility to upgrade to `Java7`

`Base64Inputstream` is of type `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream`

```
private File toBase64(File imageFile) throws Exception {
         LOG.info(this.getClass().getName() + " toBase64 method is called");
         System. out.println("toBase64 is called" );
         Base64InputStream in = new Base64InputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile), true );
         File f = new File("/root/temp/" + imageFile.getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$" , "" ) + "_base64.txt" );
         Writer out = new FileWriter(f);
         copy(in, out);
         return f;
  }

 private void copy(InputStream input, Writer output)
            throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(input);
        copy(in, output);
    }

 private int copy(Reader input, Writer output) throws IOException {
        long count = copyLarge(input, output);
        if (count > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return -1;
        }
        return (int) count;
    }

 private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

 private long copyLarge(Reader input, Writer output) {
        char[] buffer = new char[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        long count = 0;
        int n = 0;
        try {
            while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, n);
                count += n;
                System.out.println("Count: " + count);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

I was using `IOUtils.copy(InputStream input, Writer output)` method. But for some `pdf` files (note, not all) it throws exception. So, in the process of debugging I copied `IOUtils.copy` code locally and exception is thrown after `Count: 2630388`. This is the stack trace:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:268)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
```

Under what situations can this block above said throw exception:

```
while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    count += n;
                    System.out.println("Count: " + count);
                }
```

Please help me understand the cause and how can I fix it

Answer (score 2):

You should not use Reader/Writer which are *text* oriented and not *binary*, at least without encoding. They use an encoding. And PDF is binary. Either explicitly given, or the default OS encoding (unportable).

For `InputStream` use `readFully`.

And then do always a `close()`. The `copy` method, maybe leaving the close to the callers, could at least call `flush()` in that case.

---

In Java 7 there already exists a [copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29), but needs a Path and an extra option.

```
private File toBase64(File imageFile) throws Exception {
    LOG.info(this.getClass().getName() + " toBase64 method is called");
    System.out.println("toBase64 is called");
    Base64InputStream in = new Base64InputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile),
        true);
    File f = new File("/root/temp/" + imageFile.getName()
        .replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "") + "_base64.txt");

    Files.copy(in, f.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    in.close();

    return f;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on code snippet to suggested changes. Thanks

Comment: oh, good point.  OP should ditch the FileWriter and use FileOutputStream.

Comment: OP doesn't need to use readFully, just ditch the Reader/Writer.

Comment: @Learner I have added the "best" solution, using an existing function. You did not say whether Java 7 is alright.

Comment: Thanks @jtahlborn.. Your comment is actually a working answer for me. It worked after switching to `FileOutputStream` instead of `FileWriter`.

Comment: @JoopEggen Java7 is not an option for me, currently on Java6. It worked for me after switching to FileOutputStream from FileWriter. Thank you very much